# consuming kafka messages using flink 1.17 in scala version 2.11

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, flink-streaming, scala-2.11

I want to use Scala 2.11 and flink 1.17 (streaming) to consume Kafka messages. I attempted to use the flink version 1.17 library and dependency.

However, Scala 2.11 does not support flink-scala-steaming (1.17). A cross-version issue occurred when I attempted to use flink-scala-steaming (1.14), which is compatible with Scala 2.11. I also attempted to use Kafka source, but it demanded that it comes via the flink-api.

Answer (score 2):

Flink had dropped support for Scala 2.11 since Flink 1.15, see the release notes at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/release-notes/flink-1.15/#drop-support-for-scala-211

So you can't use Flink 1.17 in combination with Scala 2.11. You either need to upgrade to Scala 2.12 or downgrade to Flink 1.14.